# Minimalistic circuit to turn on an LED in both directions

Tags: led

I am trying to figure out a way to turn on an LED regardless of its direction.

Think of a socket connected to some circuitry that can check the LED direction and turn on the appropriate mosfets. Does something like this have a name?

Edit: of course this can be done very simply with a microcontroller, but I am wondering what it would take to be built with just basic active components.

Edit 2: I would love to keep max luminosity, so trying to avoid oscillating circuits (although not a bad idea)

Comment: Can you a simple bidirectional LED?

Comment: use AC voltage .

Comment: Well, if you don't care which way it's mounted, you could drive each lead with opposite polarity signals with a current limiting resistor in series.  The idea would be to toggle these signals rapidly (say at 20KHz).  

Assuming a digital circuit, you need something that will output a buffered square wave (this could be an oscillator) and an inverter, plus support circuitry to make those work (power, etc).  You would drive one lead of the LED with the input to the inverter, and the other with the output.  Make sure there is a current limiting resistor in series with the LED.

Comment: Is the problem (a) the LED so you can't change the circuit or (b) the circuit so you can't change the LED? Also does the LED need to be 100% on or is it enough it blinks so fast you can't say it blinks?

Comment: Most LEDs can take 5 V reverse voltage so if you have an AC voltage of less than 5 V peak and a resistor, it will shine (strobe) regardless of which orientation you put it in.

Comment: What voltage is available to light the LED?  There are several ways to do what you want, and each of them has a different overhead - the voltage necessary for the circuit to function independent of the voltage needed across the LED for it to light.  What voltage is available to light the LED and its circuit?  What is the forward voltage (Vf) rating of the LED?

Comment: If you put a bridge rectifier in front of Led you can connect input of rectifier in both directions.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this could work with a large enough middle voltage with a bidirectional LED and then pull the other side up or down.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjPymx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use LEDs that have two back-to-back dies [inside](https://www.kingbrightusa.com/images/catalog/SPEC/WP57SURKSURKD.pdf).

[image]

Based on BV's comment and Justme's answer here is a simulation of Justme's solution (with values and simulation). Upvote their answer if you like it.
Average current is about 5 or 6mA with the LED in either direction and the frequency is high enough it will not appear to flicker visually.

[image]

Comment: Factually correct but misunderstood the question (which says he has a socket to put an ordinary LED into)

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to build an oscillator with for example 74HC14 Hex Schmitt Trigger inverter, and then drive one LED  pin with the square wave, and drive the other LED pin with using one of the gates to invert the signal.

It needs a 5V supply and RC components to set the time constant to have high enough frequency to not notice the flickering, like few kHz.

The output and inverted output is like a H bridge to drive the LED, and use current limiting resistor to somewhere below 20mA, like having each output with 220 ohm resistor.